# How to validate form radios and add css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I have a form with some radio buttons that are displayed as labels, I am trying to add some validation to the form by adding Red border CSS to the radios/labels or outer div, to show that a radio hasn't been checked yet when the user hits submit.

I have tried doing this 2 different ways so far but nothing seems to be working, I will add both attempts below.

This is my first attempt..

```js
function validate() {
  var label = document.getElementById('title');
  if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length === 0) {
    $("#title").css('border', '3px red solid');
    } else {
      $("#title").css('border', '');
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 3px solid red !important;
}




input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=radio] + label:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid royalblue !important;
}

/*
  Change the look'n'feel of labels (which are adjacent to radiobuttons).
  Add some margin, padding to label
*/
input[type=radio] + label {
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:12px;
    width:24%;
    border:1px solid black !important;
    border-radius:4px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
/*
 Change background color for label next to checked radio button
 to make it look like highlighted button
*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
  background-image: none;
  border:2px solid royalblue !important;
  opacity:0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input type="radio" id="title" required>
  <label class="tg" for="title">
    test
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="title2" required>
  <label class="tg" for="title2">
    test
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="title3" required>
  <label class="tg" for="title3">
    test
  </label>
  <input type="submit" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

And here is my second attempt..

```js
function validateForm() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("group_1", "group_2");
  var formValid = false;

  var i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;
  }

  if (!formValid) {
    $("#s1").css('border', '3px red solid');
    $("#s2").css('border', '3px red solid');
    $("#s3").css('border', '3px red solid');
    $("#s4").css('border', '3px red solid');
  }
  return formValid;
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]+label {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px;
  width: 24%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-image: none;
  border: 2px solid royalblue !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.error {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <input type="radio" id="s1" name="group_1" value="1" />
  <label for="s1">Option 1</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="s2" name="group_1" value="2" />
  <label for="s2">Option 2</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="s3" name="group_2" value="1" />
  <label for="s3">Option 1a</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="s2" name="group_2" value="2" />
  <label for="s2">Option 2a</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br />
</form>
```

Comment: One thing that you're _not_ doing — "A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same name." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group - You're first example doesn't use a name at all, you're 2nd is using 2 different names which may be ok, but then I'd expect the requirement to be one radio from each group is selected. If these aren't mutually exclusive choices with a choice being required then maybe a radio button is the wrong type of control to use.

Answer (score 0):

Both attempts were pretty close.

Issues that are preventing your code working:

Attempt 1:

- In order to prevent a submit button working, the onclick function must return a value.  This cannot be the default return (undefined), it must be explicitly an explicit value. (i.e. `foo() { }` won't prevent submit, but `foo() { return false }` will)
- The `id` attribute must be unique (You re-use "title")

Attempt 2:

- Similar `id` issues to Attempt 1 (multiple uses of "s2")
- You're trying to set the border of the label for a radio, but the CSS selector is returning the radio, not the label.

Here's a fixed version of attempt 2:

```js
function validateGroups() {
  let valid = true
  const groups = [ "group_1", "group_2" ];
  for (group of groups) {
    radios = $(`input[name=${group}]`)
    if ($(`input[name=${group}]:checked`).length === 0)  {
      for (radio of radios) {
        $(radio).next('label').css('border', '2px solid red');
      }
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

function validateForm(form) {
  if (!validateGroups()) {
    event.preventDefault()
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]+label {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px;
  width: 24%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background-image: none;
  border: 2px solid royalblue !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.error {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
  <input type="radio" id="s1_1" name="group_1" value="1" />
  <label for="s1_1">Option 1</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="s1_2" name="group_1" value="2" />
  <label for="s1_2">Option 2</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="s2_1" name="group_2" value="1" />
  <label for="s2_1">Option 1a</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" id="s2_2" name="group_2" value="2" />
  <label for="s2_2">Option 2a</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br />
</form>
```